# Set Footer to Bottom of Page without using Fixed Position.

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me crazy I cannot work out why my footer appearing at different heights even though it is defined in the _Layout view. I have the following css:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffd800;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(/Content/SiteImages/logosmall.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 110px;
    border-top: 3px solid #082603;
}

    .footer p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: #082603;
        font-size: 150%;
        font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'
    }
```

HTML:(_Layout)

```
 <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()

        <div class="footer"><p>Quote</p> </div>

    </div>
```

How can I get the div to stay at the very bottom of the page. I want it to be under below all content. not covering any so if I add another div the foot will always be a footer. Example of my problem:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Please help me get this consistent across my multiple pages. I have looked at lots of questions on stackoverflow but none or resolving the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CSS for Fixed Footer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788357/css-for-fixed-footer), ["Fix footer to bottom of page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550) and [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to position your footer `fixed`, then offset its height (`110px`) from the bottom of the body or containing element (since it is taken out of the normal document flow), **e.g:** `.container.body-content {padding-bottom: 110px;}`

```css
.container.body-content {
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    height: 1000px; /* Force height on body */
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffd800;
  text-align: center;  
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(/Content/SiteImages/logosmall.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 110px;
  border-top: 3px solid #082603;
}

.footer p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #082603;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-content">

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Quote</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Varying Footer Height (Responsive Concern)**

If the footer height varies based on the width of the screen, refer to this answer: [Keeping footer at bottom of responsive website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426405/keeping-footer-at-bottom-of-responsive-website/32427595#32427595)

And the solution demonstrated in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoNBZX

**No Fixed Footer**

But if you need an `absolute` positioned footer, add `position: relative` to the containing element (`.container.body-content`), so that the `bottom: 0` value of `.footer` is always relative to `.container.body-content`.

```css
.container.body-content {
    height: 1000px; /* Force height on body */
    position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffd800;
  text-align: center;  
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(/Content/SiteImages/logosmall.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 110px;
  border-top: 3px solid #082603;
}

.footer p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #082603;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-content">

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Quote</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

*Edit: `position: absolute` alternative version included*

Comment: Thank you the position: absolute solved it perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to give the main wrapper a minimum height, which will push the footer down. That minimum height should be the height of the screen minus other heights (footer's, nav's etc. heights). [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tv64mb9q/1/).

> HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header">Nav area</div>
<div id="main">Main content to be here</div>
<div id="footer">Footer be here</div>  
</body>
```

> CSS:

```
#header{
  height:30px
}
#main{
  min-height:calc(100vh - 60px);
}
#footer{
  height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` for the .footer css

Comment: I have tried that. It makes the footer float when I scroll so it constantly stay in the middle of the page

Comment: Whats the CSS? for .body-content

Comment: change `bottom: 0` and `left: 0` to `bottom: 0px` and `left: 0px`

Comment: the use `position: relative` but be aware that if your body doesn't take up at least the height of the screen, it will look pretty weird

Comment: @Akerra Then just consider your main content section as having a min height.  This way a very small page with little content won't look too squished.

Answer (score 0):

change the position to

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffd800;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(/Content/SiteImages/logosmall.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 110px;
    border-top: 3px solid #082603;
}
```

The best thing to do is to put your header,main content and your footer in a div tag as a place for your elements in a web page than put them in a it's normal flow like working on footer tag at end of the page.